# Extract value from a string in swift

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a string `"25% off"`, i want to extract only value `25` from this, how can i extract it in swift, previously i had done with objective c but in swift hoe can we do that? I have tried this code but failed,

```
 let discount = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "discount")
    print(discount)
    let index = discount?.index((discount?.startIndex)!, offsetBy: 5)
    discount?.substring(to: index!)
    print(index)
```

How can i get 25 from it?

Comment: Explain what you mean by the code "failed," and since you said you've done it with Objective-C, I'd add that code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A smart solution is to find the range of all consecutive digits from the beginning of the string with Regular Expression, the `index` way is not very reliable.

```
let discount = "25% off"
if let range = discount.range(of: "^\\d+", options: .regularExpression) {
    let discountValue = discount[range]
    print(discountValue)
}
```

You can even search for the value including the percent sign with pattern `"^\\d+%"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a numeric character set to just extract the number from that string:

```
let discount = "25% off"
let number = discount.components(separatedBy: 
             CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "") 
print(number) // 25
```

Just be sure to use the inverted var, otherwise you will get the non-numbers.